# How can I overload a operator for a class with a generic template?

Tags: c++, class

Suppose we have some templated class B:

```c++
template<class T>
class B {
public:
    B(void) { (void)static_cast<C*>((T*)0) }
    ~B(void) {}
    unsigned as_int(void) { return this->internal_state; }
private:
    unsigned internal_state;
}
```

whose template accepts the class C and its derived classes (due to the static cast in the constructor above):

```
class C {
    //something
}

class D
    : public C {
    //something
}
```

If we then have a third class A:

```
class A {
public:
    A(void) { //something };
    ~A(void) { //something };

    inline A& operator = (B<C>& rhs) { this->internal_state = rhs.as_int(); }
    inline A& operator = (B<D>& rhs) { this->internal_state = rhs.as_int(); }
private:
    unsigned internal_state;
}
```

What I wish to do is to provide an overload of the assignment operator which accepts the class B as right-hand side. In the above snippet, this works fine, however only if I overload for each template of B separately (B, B etc.). Is it possible to overload once for some generic B

Comment: Why just `template <class T> A& operator = (B<T>& rhs)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two comments. First, if you want B to only be templated on C and it's children, you should just do a static_assert instead:

```
std::static_assert(std::is_base_of<C, T>::value, "Error: T not child of C!")
```

Second, you can indeed write a generic assignment operator as anxieux suggested:

```
template <typename T>
A& operator= (B<T> & rhs) { ... } // inline implied inside class declaration
```

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't have skipped class that day :)